# May one put clean sheets on a bed for oneself--NOT launder them, just change sheets--during chol hamoed?

Tags: halacha

During Chol Hamoed, may I put clean sheets on my own bed (not a guest's) that were washed BEFORE the chag?

Comment: Why not? Because there is no Melacha- and no laundering - seems to be fine

Comment: Thank you, Shoel U'Meishiv. Moadim l'Simcha.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to - its not melechis uman (work of a craftsman, meaning specialized work), it's not a melacha, plus you could probably say that it's  letzorech moed.

Comment: How could anyone say that it's not letzorech moed?

Comment: Well even if it wasn't letzorech moed it wouldn't make a diff (I should have left that part out), butjust because you wantto do it it doesn't mean it is letzorech moed.

Comment: Thank you very much Kovy, Heshy and mbloch. I really appreciate it. Moadim l'Simcha!

Comment: @Sidney76 You, too, gutt moed!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you may. It may even be permitted to launder a single set of bedding, see Leket Yosher P104.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. In this case, it would be great to quote the sefer you are referring to. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thanks very much, Ravbruk. Moadim l'Simcha!